# Dnsmasq not working domain .local

Tags: macos, apache, macos-sierra, dnsmasq

i bought a macpro and im quite new, im configuring my development environment, and when i installed dnsmasq i cant access the "anyname.local" page, it says site cant be reached, i have everything running, apache, dnsmasq, but nothing works, i followed this tutorial above.
[Link Tut](https://mallinson.ca/osx-web-development/)

I print some information maybe someone can have any idea whats wrong.

```
dig foo.local

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> foo.local
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 3951
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;foo.local.         IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           10800   IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2018030101 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 18 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Mar  2 00:03:23 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 102
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.local` suffix should be avoided on MacOS because it is used by MacOS Bonjour service.

You can look at [Apple explanation page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203136) where they recommend to use other suffixes like: `.private`, `.intranet`, `.internal`, or `.lan`.

I personally use `.localhost`, `.test` or `.example`.

As a side note, it's also not to recommended to use `.dev` because Chrome 63 started requiring a SSL certificate for this suffix.

Hope this helps!