# Not able to use dnsmasq on macOS Catalina, pings result in `Unknown host` error

Tags: macos, dns, homebrew, macos-catalina, dnsmasq

I'm trying to get `dnsmasq` up and running on my Macbook Pro (Catalina installed), but without any luck. Dnsmasq should help me with my local development projects without updating the hosts file constantly. At first I tried to get all local domains with suffix `.local` up and running, but after each ping I received the message `ping: cannot resolve somedomain.local: Unknown host`.

After reading this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49060768/dnsmasq-not-working-domain-local) thread I replaced the suffix `.local` with `.intern`, but still no luck.

This is my setup:

**/usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf:**

```
address=/.intern/127.0.0.1
listen-address=127.0.0.1
port=5354
```

**/etc/resolver/intern**

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

After executing `sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP`, dnsmasq seems to run:

```
dnsmasq   33014         nobody    5u  IPv4 0x772f1bc094afa8cb      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:5354 (LISTEN)
```

I even added `127.0.0.1` to the DNS list of my WiFi adapter as well as my thunderbolt ethernet adapter. It does take quite longer to ping, but in the end I still get a `ping: cannot resolve test.intern: Unknown host` message.

Any thoughts what might cause this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This article saved me: https://www.stevenrombauts.be/2019/06/restart-dnsmasq-without-sudo/

Changing the port on which dnsmasq is running worked for me.